# EXCEL help, Populating text from cells not sure where to ask

Tags: excel

Im attempting to aid my co-workers with a spreadsheet that has calculated back payment dates and amounts for various things.

I have also included and example text box that reads "Pregnancy payment request received - EDD date is  [DATE]"

Where [DATE] is a cell value from the spreadsheet, I cannot however get the value to insert itself into the text. I have tried CELL() functions to pull contents. I have also tried ="string" %cell which partially worked but then fell short of formatting since i lost the dd/mm/yyyy format once it has merged with the string.

The idea is to have one text box to copy and paste from excel onto our work systems for a streamlined note summary. Is there an easy approach or a function i have not come across?

Comment: I do not get what yoi are doing, or whether you are using, VBA, or not, or why you would do it this way, but, a simple solution to your problem is to add a =FORMAT(cell,"DD/MM/YYYY") formula in another cell to convert the date to a string and then use that cell/string to concat in stead ofd the original cell with the date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a1: ="Pregnancy payment request received - EDD date is "&B1
b1: =TEXT(C1,"dd MMM yyy")
c1: put your date here:
```

Comment: Thanks this worked like a charm, I have all the data I need in one cell by using a long list of &'s. But when i try to display this in a text box it is displayed as an object rather than text i can copy and paste. 

Any thoughts?

Comment: =value() should do it? I hope I am understanding you correctly? Alternatively you can paste values.

Answer (score 0):

Try the `TEXT` function. If the date of interest were in cell B1, you would enter

`="Pregnancy payment request received - EDD date is "&TEXT(B1,"dd/mm/yyyy")`